# UIButton Set bookmarkstate only for currentIndex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Have bookmark button on the navigation bar for UIPageviewcontroller.

After bookmarking currentIndex in uipageviewcontroller when turning pageover then why selected bookmarking state is showing for all pages where as it should show for only bookmarked currentIndex not for all pages. For all pages it should show unbookmarked state.

Like when i bookmark current index bookmark button then shows blue bookmark state for that currentIndex but when i turn page over it shows blue bookmark button for the next page also when next page is not bookmarked. It should show unbookmarked state for next page as it is not bookmarked.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)bookmarkAction:(id)sender {

if ( _bookmarkbtn.tag) {

    [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _bookmarkbtn.tag = 0;
     [self setBookmarkState:NO];

} else {

    [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];     
    _bookmarkbtn.tag = 1;
    [self setBookmarkState:YES];

}

_bookmarkbtn.tag = _BookmarkState;

[self bookmarkcurrentIndex];
}

- (void)bookmarkcurrentIndex {

currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:contentViewController.page];

   // if ([contentViewController.bookmarks containsIndex:currentIndex]) {


    if (BookmarkState == YES) {

        [contentViewController.bookmarks addIndex:currentIndex];

    }else {   

      [contentViewController.bookmarks removeIndex:currentIndex];    
}

    BookmarkState = ! BookmarkState;
  }
```

Am i missing that logic from my code.

Any direction will be really appreciated.

Thanks